# Persist selected rows the correct way

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to make use of [ngGrid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/). 
The list represents a bunch of items which the users then can select (or not). This selection should be persisted so when the user comes back the grid shows the same selected items as last time. [I made a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/20R1MzxfQOdJkzMQCBHo?p=preview)

However I've run into a bit of a problem using ngGrid.

I'm using `afterSelectionChange` to save selection changes to the grid.

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  showSelectionCheckbox: true,
  afterSelectionChange: function(rowItem, event) {
    // $http... save selection state
  }
};
```

Which is fine. However when I want to select rows programmatically when the page loads all hell breaks loose. The below code is supposed to select the row with the name Enos, and it does. But it triggers `afterSelectionChange` 4 times.

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventData', function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(data, index) {
        if (data.name == 'Enos') {
            $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);
        }
    });
});
```

That can't be intended. [I made a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/20R1MzxfQOdJkzMQCBHo?p=preview).

How to persist selected rows using ngGrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why this is firing 4 Times, but it does not happen when you use selectedItems:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'myData',
  showSelectionCheckbox: true,
  selectedItems:$scope.output
};
```

Not really an answer, but maybe it helps you.

[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BrFvtGi0KEAqAhvUZRn8?p=preview)

**Update**
Found out some more:

The event `ngGridEventData` is fired 2 times:

1. On Initialization AND after `selectItem` by a watcher.
2. Also `afterSelectionChange` is fired 2 time. The rowItem from first call is a clone (from cache?) the second one is noClone.

This sums up to 4!

So by taking init out of `ngGridEventdata` and replacing it with a timeout as well as only pushing rowitems when they are a clone (why?) resolves this issue.

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    showSelectionCheckbox: true,
    afterSelectionChange: function(rowItem, event) {
      if (rowItem.isClone) {
        $scope.output.push({
          name: rowItem.entity.name,
          selected: rowItem.selected
        });
        $scope.num++;
      }
    }
    };
    setTimeout(function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(data, index) {
      if (data.name == 'Enos') {
        $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);
      }
    });
    })
```

I know this is still not an answer and smells like a bug to me, but here is another forked [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GMn5GKyGwR2SgnA36IB2?p=preview) anyhow.

Of course you now have to find a way how to splice items out of the array when they are unselected. Good Luck!

Comment: Maybe better use a watcher instead of the timeout. But what to watch when there are so many watchable things?:-)

Comment: Just to keep you informed: I found out a bit more about the ngGridEventData thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116683/persist-selected-rows-the-correct-way/23134977#23134977

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - or sort of.

Using `beforeSelectionChange` instead of `afterSelectionChange` I get the expected behavior.
The documentation is lagging some information.