# ng-grid : Why is afterSelectionChange() called twice?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I did not like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504761/angular-nggrid-select-row-on-page-load/19391176#comment35828136_19391176). To my mind, it has a bad code smell. I am new to Angular, so I thought I could learn something if I created a Plunk to help that questioner.

My Plunk is http://plnkr.co/edit/fJcew7cGCPzJ0nhIQXjg?p=preview, but there two things which I don't understand. Here's the code for the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        <p>Press F12 and look at the Console log</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note that I assigned the ng-grid's data two ways - at one fell stroke and row by row. Comment one out & uncomment the other to play around with it.

And be sure to press F12 to see the developer's console log messages.

1. why am I getting TWO ngGridEventData events?
2. why, when I push() row by row am I not getting one ngGridEventData event per push() ?
   I am trying to implement master/detail/even more detailed with 3 grids (nothing to do with the current question) and have been googling for a few days now. Many people seem believe that they will get multiple ngGridEventData events and want to know ho to detect that the grid is fully rendered (hence the check in my Plunk).

In short, how does ngGridEventData work in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recent Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116683/persist-selected-rows-the-correct-way/23134977#23134977) I showed some learnings about this strange behavior. It seems that this routine is called 2 times for reasons I can't really understand (caching maybe?).

You can get this to work if you only react when the data-object is a clone:

```
  if (data.selected === true) {
    if (data.isClone) {
      numSelectionChanges = numSelectionChanges + 1;
      console.log("afterSelectionChange", 'Selection has chanegd ' + numSelectionChanges + ' times');
      console.table(data);
    }
  }
```

Give it a try, and if you find out why this happens please let me know.

**More findings update:**

Have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JxnIjXgkTWMutgJHejQ2?p=preview)

I have included the ng-grid.js script directly in the plunker.
If you look at rows 3344-3349 you will find this piece of code:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.$parent.$watch(options.data, dataWatcher));
$scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.$parent.$watch(options.data + '.length', function() {
     dataWatcher($scope.$eval(options.data));
     $scope.adjustScrollTop(grid.$viewport.scrollTop(), true);
}));
```

As you can see the there are two watchers applied which looks like a leftover from changes to me. *(Although i'm not sure, with me being dumb and those guys being clever)*. However, if I comment the first line out everything seems to work as expected.

Be carefull when you try this out, because it may break other functionality. I'm not very comfortable with hacking in such a lengthy source code. If someone who is an actual ng-grid team member sees this he can tell me if I found a bug and how to report it. (Never done that before!)

Comment: +1 and thanks. A few comments, however. Please see the new Plunk at http://plnkr.co/edit/fJcew7cGCPzJ0nhIQXjg?p=preview  On lines 29 & 30, we can now detect the clone in afterSelectionChange()  However, if we comment out line 64 for a clearer console log, then see line 43. ngGridEventData is still being called twice, which I do not understand, and both times row.isClone is undefined, so I guess it is called for two different reasons.  Any idea? I don't like this "double cal" as I go to a server to fetch a lot of data.

Comment: I'm at home for the weekend and due to recent changes in FF my debugging does not work very well on my laptop:-\ I'll have a closer look on Monday. From my last extensive debug runs I know that GridEvent is in fact triggered a second time from a watcher inside ng-grid. The changeSelection function fires GridEvent and the watcher that watches the GridData fires the event again, when it has been changed. This seems like a bug to me, although those guys that wrote ng-grid are way more clever than me and may have an idea behind this. I still have to find out where the data for both events differs.

Comment: Look at the update of my answer and keep me informed if this helped you.

Comment: +1 It may well be a bug. Let's see if can bring the ng-grid team's attention to it. Even when I am 10% sure i am correct, I don't like to hack other people's code as I then must mintain my hack for every new release. Far better to ask them to incorporate a change.

Comment: Looks like this issue was already known and closed with this workaround: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/585 Works without hacking the source. I prefer it that way too.