# In ng-grid gridOptions.$gridScope.columns is changed twice on hide/show columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, show-hide, ng-grid, watch

**Question 1:**

Why

```
$scope.$watch('gridOptions.$gridScope.columns', function(newv, oldv) {
    console.log('Changed');
}
```

is called **twice** when I **hide/show** a column manually (using showColumnMenu:true in code), but it is called only **one time** when I **reorder**/**sort** columns manually (using enableColumnReordering:true in code)?

I observed that if I use:

```
// column number 0
$scope.$watch('gridOptions.$gridScope.columns[0]', function(newv, oldv) {
    console.log('Changed');
}
```

and I show/hide a column that is not 0 (E.g.: hide column 5) the function is called (not twice). So, I believe that on hide/show the whole ng-grid is changed, then only that column is changed.

How can I see which are the events for every situation ?

**Question 2**:

How can I **stop** the **second call** or the **first call** of the function ?

---

I tried to debug the following pieces of code from AngularJS:

```
if ((watchers = current.$$watchers)) {
    // process our watches
    length = watchers.length;
...
watch.fn(value, ((last === initWatchVal) ? value : last), current);
...
// in the case user pass string, we need to compile it, do we really need this ?
if (!isFunction(listener)) {
    var listenFn = compileToFn(listener || noop, 'listener');
    watcher.fn = function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {listenFn(scope);};
}
```

and I could observe that `watchers[4]` and `watchers[5]` have the same "exp" (`gridOptions.$gridScope.columns`) and `watchers[5]` has my function as fn while `watchers[4]` has a function that calls `listenFn(scope)`.

I also tried to use `$gridScope.renderedColumns`, but there was the same problem.

Comment: Maybe this answer could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419722/ng-grid-why-is-afterselectionchange-called-twice/23426604#23426604 Seems to address a similar issue.

Comment: There is something similar, but my problem cannot be solved using that solution. In my case, the problem seems to be related to this part of code:
             $scope.$on('$destroy', $scope.$watch('columns', function (a) {
    console.log($scope.isColumnResizing); // undefined
                if(!$scope.isColumnResizing){
                    domUtilityService.RebuildGrid($scope, self); // maybe to comment
                }
    console.log("$scope.$emit('ngGridEventColumns', a);");
                $scope.$emit('ngGridEventColumns', a);
            }, true));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that doesn't change ng-grid code and AngularJS code:

```
var ok = 0 ;
$scope.$watch('gridOptions.$gridScope.columns', fff, true);
function fff(newv, oldv){
    if ( oldv !== newv && oldv.length === newv.length ) {
        if ( areTheyEqual(oldv, newv) || isReordered(oldv, newv) ) {
            console.log('\n\n=====  ' + (ok++) + ' =====');
        }
    }
}

function isReordered(oldv, newv) {
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < oldv.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( oldv[i].originalIndex !== newv[i].originalIndex ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function areTheyEqual(oldv, newv) {
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < oldv.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( oldv[i].width !== newv[i].width ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now `console.log` is called only once for every operation: **resize**, **hide**, **show**, **reorder**, **sort**.

---

If you want to do something like: react to **reorder**/**show**/**hide**:

```
var ok = 0;
$scope.$watch('gridOptions.$gridScope.columns', functionForColumnsChange, true);

function functionForColumnsChange(newv, oldv){
    if ( oldv !== newv && oldv.length === newv.length ) {
        if ( isHideOrShowAction(oldv, newv) || isReordered(oldv, newv) ) {
            console.log('\n\n=====  ' + (ok++) + ' =====');
        }
    }
}

function isReordered(oldv, newv) {
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < oldv.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( oldv[i].originalIndex !== newv[i].originalIndex ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function isHideOrShowAction(oldv, newv) {
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < oldv.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( oldv[i].visible !== newv[i].visible ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```